# Zimbra Right Click zimlet ... possible?

Tags: zimbra

Is it possible to change the context menu that pops up on right clicking an email item row (the type that shows up in the middle panel of zimbra). [Here's an example](http://cl.ly/image/180J0i0R3Q3D) ...

The ContentObject Type is close but I can't seem to find anything conclusive.

Total zimbra/zimlet newb too btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely add items. (I've only added, not deleted items). Basically, you're going to put the functionality in

```
onActionMenuInitialized = function(controller, actionMenu) {
  // do some stuff here that adds a menu item
  // and make sure you add a selection listener to that item.
}
```

There's an example you can follow at [the Zimbra forum.](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/developers/2111-context-menu-confusion.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked this with Zimbra 8.6.0.

```
// You should run this code after "Mail" app initialization
// (after its tab activation if you want to check this manually via browser console or
// after "app launched" event notification in your zimlet, see ZmZimletBase.prototype.appLaunch documentation)

var ml = DwtControl.ALL_BY_ID["zl__CLV-main"];

var menu = new ZmPopupMenu(ml);
var mi = menu.createMenuItem("some_id", {text: "Click me"});
mi.addSelectionListener(new AjxListener(null, function(){ console.log("you've just clicked 'Click me' menu item") }));
menu.createSeparator();
mi = menu.createMenuItem("another_id", {text: "Another action"});
mi.addSelectionListener(new AjxListener(null, function(){ console.log("you've just clicked 'Another action' menu item") }));

var listeners = ml._evtMgr._listeners[ZmEvent.S_ACTION];
listeners.removeAll();
var listener = new AjxListener(null, function(ev) {
    menu.setLocation(ev.docX, ev.docY);
    menu.popup();
});
listeners.add(listener);
```